# Is there a way to correct false values (-9999) to NA in a tiff-layers in R?

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, tiff

I am trying to create a climate model in ArcGIS Pro, which will supposedly tell me which environmental variables have the biggest effect on fungal communities. However, I tried the exploratory regression and the environmental variables have insignificant effects, which is nearly impossible due to extensive research already done.

My shapefile containing info on fungal richness has to mistakes, it has been checked. But my tif containing 27 variables doesn't seem to be properly made. I checked in R and there are in fact -9999 values that are messing up the modelling. Although I know that there are incorrect values in the tif-file, I don't know how I can correct them and nothing I do seems to be working.

I tried the following code to replace -9999 values into NA directly in the raster layers:

```
env <- terra::rast("EnvPredictor_1km_IK_norm.tif")

[1] "EnvPredictor_1km_IK_norm_1"  "EnvPredictor_1km_IK_norm_2"` 
[3] "EnvPredictor_1km_IK_norm_3"  "EnvPredictor_1km_IK_norm_4" 
[5] "EnvPredictor_1km_IK_norm_5"  

env$EnvPredictor_1km_IK_norm_1[env$EnvPredictor_1km_IK_norm_1 == -9999] <- NA
env$EnvPredictor_1km_IK_norm_2[env$EnvPredictor_1km_IK_norm_2 == -9999] <- NA
env$EnvPredictor_1km_IK_norm_3[env$EnvPredictor_1km_IK_norm_3 == -9999] <- NA
env$EnvPredictor_1km_IK_norm_4[env$EnvPredictor_1km_IK_norm_4 == -9999] <- NA
env$EnvPredictor_1km_IK_norm_5[env$EnvPredictor_1km_IK_norm_5 == -9999] <- NA

writeRaster(env, "D:/EIE_Macroecology/00_datasets/Updated_EnvPredictor_1km_IK_norm.tif", overwrite = TRUE)
```

The code doesn't seem to have any issues, but in ArcGIS it doesn't change. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure, but do you have a parse error from your code? `== -9999]NA` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
library(terra)
env <- terra::rast("EnvPredictor_1km_IK_norm.tif")
out <- subst(env, -9999, NA, filename="new_file.tif")
```